# Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent not called when ContextMenu showing

Tags: android, motionevent, android-contextmenu

I'm seeing that when a `ContextMenu` is displaying, from using `View.showContextMenu()`, the `Activity` that contains the view isn't getting a chance to consume motion events in `dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent)`. I'm trying to consume events from a connected controller, and direct those inputs elsewhere, and it works fine in every case except when the menu is showing.

Is there another method within the activity to override and intercept the motion events that way?

Is this expected behavior, or a quirk of the phone I'm testing on?

Comment: A context menu is a separate window from your activity's window, so it would be expected that your activity doesn't get those motion events.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you! That was what I was assuming, but couldn't find a source online to confirm. Do you know of a way to intercept the events on that Window as well?